# Completing an abandoned PayPal contribution

Tags: paypal

I have PayPal standard set up as a payment processor for membership subscription payments.

If a user does not successfully complete the process then they get set up as a contact, an account is created in WordPress but the membership payment contribution gets stuck at "Pending (Incomplete Transaction)".

Is there any way to allow the user to complete the transaction?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is currently now way to resubmit a pending contribution either from the front or the back end of Civi - it would be best to cancel the pending contribution and contact the donor to request that they resubmit their membership contribution.

Kind regards,
Tamar